# How to make vim show search result list dynamically while :tj SomeSymbol is being typing?

Tags: vim

all. I know after generating a tag file, when I use `:tj SomeSymbol`, I can either jump to the expected location when `SomeSymbol` is unique within the project, or be given a list to choose. But I want more convenient way.

When I'm typing `:tj SomeSymbol`, I wish there's a popup menu showing all possible locations as if vim was searching the tag file for the expected symbol. In this way I can choose quickly and conveniently.

The final effect I want may be like what qtcreator gives:
[image]

> So is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in. Vim's *completion popup menu* currently can only be used for selecting candidate matches to be inserted into the text; it's not a general-purpose selector / filter. For tags, Vim only offers the selection by number as in the `:tselect` / `:tjump` commands. However, some plugins have implemented custom filtering (often in combination with *fuzzy matching* for easy drill-down into the candidate lists). I still use [FuzzyFinder](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984), which (though unmaintained for quite some time) offers (among others) a `:FufTag` command that lets you interactively select from tag matches.